# Postman "Error creating interceptor session"

Tags: postman

I installed the Postman interceptor Chrome extension, the Postman interceptor and the custom Node version I was asked to install and once I try to start the capture I get a toast telling me that there is an "Error creating interceptor session" without any further useful information.

[image]

Following the [troubleshooting tips](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/#troubleshooting-tips) I verified that:

- Chrome is installed
- the directory `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts` exists.
- I have a working internet connection.
- my firewall allows Postman to connect to the internet.
- I have permissions to read and write in the `~/.postman/InterceptorBridge` directory.
- I have write permissions to my `~/Downloads` folder.
- `which node` yields `/usr/local/bin/node`
- the manifest file `com.postman.postmanapp.json` is not in `~/.postman` but the documentation does not tell where it is even supposed to be. I deleted `~/.postman` and reinstalled Postman. The directory did not reappear. The error persisted. I have no possibility to reinstall the interceptor from within Postman now.
- Before deleting `~/.postman` the Interceptor binary existed therein but is obviously gone now.
- Executing `pm.interceptorInstaller.reset()` in the Postman dev tools did not enable me to reinstall the interceptor either. The error persists.

I appreciate any help.

- Postman version: 9.15.8
- Chrome version: 100.0.4896.60
- macOS version: 12.3